# How do I solve this problem without a given equation?

Tags: calculus, newton-raphson

Do I need an equation to figure out $x_2$ and $x_3$ values? Can the equation be obtained from the graph? Much thanks!
[image]

Comment: Not only can the values be obtained from the graph, but the problem suggests how to do it: draw tangent lines.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you draw the tangent to the curve at $x_1=6$, it looks like it will intersect the $x$ axis at $x_2=8$. Drawing the tangent at $x_2=8$ will intersect the $x$-axis at $x_3=7$